# linux -- relinquishing your CPU time slice programatically in user mode

Tags: cpu, scheduler

What I'd like to do is to code a process like the following:

```
while(forever)
     {
     do something;
     relinquish current cpu time slice;
     }
```

Is there some call to make in Linux that simply terminates your time slice so that the forever loop will not hog the entire a CPU thread?  I'm sure you can make another system call or something but that invokes possibly unnecessary kernel/user CPU work, I just want to say I am done with my timeslice and reschedule.

This type of call could also be very nice in a realtime environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sched_yield(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) system call does exactly what you want. Just `#include <sched.h>` and call `sched_yield();`.

Comment: Excellent, been searching for this for awhile apparently did not hit on the right keyword to search for.